# how to i remove characheters from the prefix table and make sure only from the start of string are removed

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I need to be able to strip the following prefixes from product codes as you see I have included a simple query while yes the below shows me the cm im not wanting i cant use replace  as it code replace any instance of cm the prefixes are held in the supplire table cross refer with the products table

prefixes are not always two chrachters for example can be TOW

```
SELECT *  , left(prod.productcode, LEN(sup.prefix)) AS MyTrimmedColumn
FROM MSLStore1_Products prod  ,supplier sup
WHERE prod.suppid = 9039 AND prod.SgpID = 171
and sup.supno = prod.suppid
```

Product Codes:

```
ProductCode
CMDI25L
CMDI300M
CMDI750M
CMXFFP5L
```

Prefixes:

```
Prefix
CM
CM
CM
CM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUBSTRING()` for that:

```
SUBSTRING(prod.productcode, LEN(sup.prefix))
```

(concrete syntax may vary for different database-managers)

Comment: i solved it with this 

  SELECT *  , right(prod.productcode, len(prod.productcode) - LEN(sup.prefix) ) AS MyTrimmedColumn
 FROM MSLStore1_Products prod  ,supplier sup
 WHERE prod.suppid = 9217 AND prod.SgpID = 123 and sup.supno = prod.suppid

Comment: Yes, that has the same result. But i don't know if the additional `LEN()` needs more effort.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your prefixes in another table, and run the productCode field through a filtering UDF to retrieve the final code.

Something like

SELECT *  , dbo.FilterPCode(prod.productcode) AS MyTrimmedColumn
FROM MSLStore1_Products prod  ,supplier sup
WHERE prod.suppid = 9039 AND prod.SgpID = 171
and sup.supno = prod.suppid

then just define a UDF that takes a string product code and removes any prefix from the front.

You might see a performance hit using a UDF like this for really massive queries, and if that's the case, it might be better to generate a table of table of product codes without the prefix linked to the product codes with the prefix. Don't know enough about the data schema to know if that's truly possible without getting cross links though.

Answer (score 0):

how do i thought use this query  and imortant the results from that into the products table external code field

```
 SELECT *  , right(prod.productcode, len(prod.productcode) - LEN(sup.prefix) ) AS ExternalCoode
 FROM MSLStore1_Products prod  ,supplier sup
 WHERE prod.suppid = 9217 AND prod.SgpID = 123 and sup.supno = prod.suppid
```

Comment: Who are you addressing? This isn't really an answer, more like a comment. When you earn a little more rep, the system will trust you and you can post comments anywhere. In the meantime, please refrain from posting comments as answers.  Thanks.